# align text from right to left in c# windows form application while printing

Tags: c#

i am fresher(learner),I am working on my test project,i have some text to print for that i have used print-document, everything is working fine, but for two lines at the end total quantity and grand total i want to show text to align right to left like for item price, money while billing as usual seen.
hope you understood, please help, below is the code

```
  private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {

        e.Graphics.DrawString("Welcome ", new Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(280, 8));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("company name ", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(10, 50));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Auto Center", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(10, 75));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("address,", new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(10, 95));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("address,", new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(10, 115));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(" po box - 00000.", new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(10, 135));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("GST       : Owner GST Number", new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(10, 155));

        e.Graphics.DrawString("abc. : " + abc.Text.Trim(), new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(10, 175));



        e.Graphics.DrawString("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(10, 195));

        e.Graphics.DrawString("Sl", new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(05, 210));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("No.", new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(05, 228));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Product Name", new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(45, 210));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Amount", new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(370, 228));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("UOM", new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(450, 210));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Quantity", new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(500, 210));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Unit Price", new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(575, 210));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("(Rs.)", new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(575, 228));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Total", new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(665, 210));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("(Rs.)", new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(665, 228));

        e.Graphics.DrawString("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(10, 235));

        int ypos = 250;

        while (i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count)
        {

            if (ypos > e.MarginBounds.Height)
            {
                ypos = 250;
                e.HasMorePages = true;
                return;
            }
            numberofitemsprinted++;

            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(8, ypos));

            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(48, ypos));



            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].FormattedValue.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(455, ypos));

            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].FormattedValue.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(500, ypos));

            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].FormattedValue.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(580, ypos));

            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[11].FormattedValue.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(670, ypos));


            i++;
            ypos = ypos + 30;

        }

        e.Graphics.DrawString("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(10, ypos));

        e.Graphics.DrawString("Total Quantity (Rs)             : " +txtTotaQuantity.Text.Trim(), new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(460, ypos + 60));

        e.Graphics.DrawString("Grand Total (Rs)            : " + txtGrandTotal.Text.Trim(), new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(460, ypos + 80));

        e.Graphics.DrawString("Amount in Words : " + txtAmountWords.Text.Trim() + " ONLY", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(20, ypos + 120));



        numberofitemsperpage = 0;
        numberofitemsprinted = 0;
    }
```

Comment: dont draw the string at 8 or 48 but width of page - width of string.....

Comment: Graphics.DrawString() has lots of overloads.  For printing you generally favor the one that takes a RectangleF, so you'll specify the rectangle to be filled with the string, and a StringFormat, so you can specify the alignment.